# Instance variables and Inheritance

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

Currently I am trying to calculate the distance between the Image1 and Player classes, in my `main()`. My variables of interest are Bx,By,Px, and Py seen below. Currently I can get the images in the Pygame window to update and print out their respective coordinates in real time. However I would like to have access to the individual variables so I can implement a distance variable.

```py
class Image1(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, img, all_active_sprites):
        super().__init__()

        #scale player image
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(ImageOne, (100, 100))
        self.image.set_colorkey(BLACK)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        #set spawn location for image
        self.rect.x = random.randrange(25, WINDOWWIDTH - 25)
        self.rect.y = random.randrange(25, WINDOWHEIGHT - 25)

        #set speed/direction
        self.speed_x = random.choice([-1,1])
        self.speed_y = random.choice([-1,1])

    def update(self):
        ''' update Image1 class '''
        self.rect.y += self.speed_y
        self.rect.x += self.speed_x

        #simulate zigzag movement

        "Omitted for Space - Movement Rules"

        #calculate coordinates
        Bx = self.rect.x
        By = self.rect.y
        coordinates_Image1 = (Bx,By)
        print("Image1 Position:",coordinates_Image1)

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, player_img,all_active_sprites):
        super().__init__()
        #scale player image
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(player_img, (25, 25))
        self.image.set_colorkey(BLACK)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        #player starting location
        self.rect.x = WINDOWWIDTH / 2
        self.rect.y = WINDOWHEIGHT/ 2

        #player speed
        self.speed_x = 0
        self.speed_y = 0

    def update(self):
        '''update the Player class'''
        #arrow controls
        "Omitted for Space - Key Commands"

        #update movement, stop at boundaries
        self.rect.x += self.speed_x
        self.rect.y += self.speed_y

        "Omitted for Space - Movement Rules"

        #calculate coordinates
        Px = self.rect.x
        Py = self.rect.y
        coordinates_player = Px,Py
        print("Player Position:",coordinates_player)
```

My thinking was that I needed to find a way to access these instance variables outside of the locale, so what I tried as a solution was as follows. I separated the coordinates into their own functions inside each class, away from the movement calculations. Then in my `main()` I created an instance for each class, `p = Player(args)` for example. I then called the coordinate functions from my `main()`, and the paired coordinates, (x,y), would print as before but I still could not access/print the individual variables desired. Not sure what I'm doing wrong. Thank you and be well!

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. In particular, show the relevant code from the `main()` function which you describe in words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variables `Px` and `Py` are only in scope in the `update()` function. They are called "local variables". On the other hand, you have a variable named `p` which represents an entire player. It has a field `p.rect` that is its bounding rectangle. And from there you can access `p.rect.x` and `p.rect.y`.